# How do CPUs work and its relation to the CPU usage of a process

Tags: cpu

I found that there are many people suggest setting the priority of one process to "Realtime" in task manager and requesting ways to make a process run in 100% CPU usage.

 
However, with the situation of CPU usage currently not 100% in task manager, is it useless to give a process a higher cap as all of the processes that are currently running doesn’t even exceed the capability of my CPU?

 Or for example, assume program A costs 5 CPU units to run. Program A will run faster if I give it a 100 units resources instead of 50 units despite that it doesn’t use all of the resources in both situations?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to increase priority for a process when it is possible that the process is delayed by other processes with high CPU usage.

If that process uses a low amount of CPU resources (let's say 5%), making it real-time will make no difference, generally speaking; it will still use 5%, but no other lower priority process will be able to steal that 5%.

Practically, priorities are used to reserve CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is some program will not use more CPU because they are not designed to be multi-threaded.  Most programs are still single threaded, and some can use more than 1 core, but only under certain conditions.

Some of this is because the program is not written to take advantage of more than a single core.  Sometimes, a task can not be made to use multiple cores because you have to wait for part 1 to complete before part 2 starts.

In some cases a program can be re-written to support multi-threading, but it will probably take a lot of time and money so good luck convincing the developer to do it.  Unless of course you had him a blank check, and pay for it.